# how to get parent navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

In my `AppDelegate`, I have a main `NavigationController` that is a "drawer controller" from a third party framework.  In there, I have some more controllers, and in my `pageTabBarController` I a `PostsViewController` for each page, and that `PostsViewController` contains a tableview.  **My goal is to navigate the user to a new controller when he taps a cell in that tableview.**

Check out the **AppDelegate.swift** setup:

```
var viewControllers = [NavigationController]()

for name in categories {
    let navTmp = NavigationController(rootViewController: 
    PostsViewController(category: name))
    navTmp.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    viewControllers.append(navTmp)
}

let pageTabBarController = AppPageTabBarController(viewControllers: viewControllers)

let toolbarController = AppToolbarController(rootViewController: pageTabBarController)
let menuMainController = MenuViewController()
let drawerController = AppNavigationDrawerController(rootViewController: toolbarController, leftViewController: menuMainController)

window = UIWindow(frame: Screen.bounds)
window!.rootViewController = drawerController
window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

I believe that I will need the parent navigation controller to do this.  Bear with me, I am new to swift.  But again, **my goal is to navigate the user to a new controller when he taps a cell.**

Edit: Looking back at this, it looks like I need to make that controller class embedded in a navigation controller, and hook one up to each `PostsViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you're using CosmicMind's Material. So you have to put your code which navigating the view controller in the `tableView` delegate in a specific UIViewController class, **not** inside the `AppDelegate`.

Comment: Yes, I am using Material.  I tried that and I couldn't get it to work-- I tried instantiating a navigationcontroller, putting a new viewcontroller inside, and pushing it on but nothing happened :(

Comment: No need to do that, all you need to do is handling the navigation inside the view controller that you want to start your navigation, here is `PostsViewController `. Now focus on the `tableView` inside of it, when user taps on a tableView `Cell`, the delegate `didSelectRowAt` is called, do your work here:  
  
let nextVC = NewViewController() // or instantiate the view controller here.  
navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)

Comment: You didn't explain it well enough for a newbie like me to understand it right away, but I finally got there.  Thanks!